# move_uploaded_file() not working in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload files (images) with this PHP script and I'm getting errors. Yes, I know that there are other questions on here that ask the same thing, but I didn't find any of them usefull.

Here's my script (the short version):

```
//*** FILE IS NAMED 'imageUpload' IN THE INC FOLDER ***

$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$location = "usr/profile/$image_name";
move_uploaded_file($image_tmpName,'../img/'.$location);
```

Here's my file tree (CAPITOLS-folders , lower-file):

```
1. IMG
    -USR
        *PROFILE
2. INC
    -imageUpload.php
```

The errors that I'm getting:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../img/usr/profile/Cheese.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/35/9611635/html/chsyearbook/inc/imageUpload.php on line 12

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpuLkkjE' to '../img/usr/profile/Cheese.jpg' in /home/content/35/9611635/html/chsyearbook/inc/imageUpload.php on line 12
```

Now these errors are clearly saying that the directory doesn't exist, but I assur you, I'm looking at it right now.

I think this might be a problem with the PHP.ini file. if so, here's the PHP.ini (why not, eh?)

```
max_execution_time = 60;
memory_limit = 256M;
upload_max_filesize = 256M;
post_max_size =  256M;
```

Comment: It can't be a problem with `php.ini`. It can be a problem with a relative path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some comments on the php manual page for the function that suggest using a relative path here does not work as expected.

https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file

[edit]

try checking the working directory with the `getcwd()` function before calling move_uploaded_file. This should tell you what directory the relative path is... relative to.